# Waiting for a process to end

Tags: bash, process

I would like to run `n` processes (in my case simulations) simultaneously, so I'm using `&` like so:

```
for i in {1..50};
do
     run simulation &
done
```

After each simulation is done I need to parse its output files. My question is how do I know when a process is done, and what do I do to invoke a function upon finishing a process?

EDIT: I think what I need to do is call a function that would invoke the simulation and parse its files after it is done. The way I see it this function has to be a child process anyway, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't seem to want/need to wait until *all* simulations are done, you can simply do this:

```
for i in {1..50};
do
     { run simulation && parse output; } &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wait` builtin utility. See `man bash` for more information. In the simplest case, `wait` by itself will wait for all child processes to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

The `wait` builtin waits for all child to finish.  If you want to execute a command for each jobs that finishes, you can use `trap`.  In your case, a combination of `wait` and `trap` should work:

```
trap parse_output SIGCHLD
for i in {1..50}; do
  run simulation &
done
wait
```